# Why does my PDF repeat the last edit I made to an included image?

Tags: pdf

I have a multi-page PDF that has an image on its first page that I recently edited before re-saving the PDF. The edit involved changing the number 46 to 40 by pasting a 0 on top of the 6 and then adjusting its position.

Now when I open the PDF it shows me the last step of the edit - in motion! It moves the 0 slightly until it's in the right place.

What on earth is going on and how can I stop this?

This behaviour is displayed both with Adobe Acrobat and PDF Xchange Viewer.

Comment: It could be that the PDF is an image and when you corrected it you placed a text character there. Thus the `0` exists only as an overlay on top of the image.